# salesforce validation across multiple objects

Tags: validation, salesforce

How to write a validation rule so that The Quote Billing Entity , Quote lines Billing Entity,  The Opportunity Billing Entity ,  the Order Billing Entity should be same all the time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, assuming you manage to do it. How do you hope to ever create new or edit existing records :D there will have to be the 1st record that's out of sync to the rest and what, you'll block all edits ever?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.